# How to set the relative order of columns with a zfdatagrid?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zfdatagrid

To those of you who are familiar with zfdatagrid for the Zend framework:

I got a recordset by a JOIN query, say from tables s and t, now I want to set the order in which the columns appear in the deployed table.

For example,

5th column of table t to appear at the leftmost side,
then 3rd column of table s,
then 2nd column of table t,
then 4th column of table s.

How do I do this? Whatever I tried, it always shows first the columns of the left table of the JOIN, then the columns of the right table of the JOIN.

I only know how to tell it which columns to show, but not their order.

Answer (score 2):

It may be late but may be useful for others

You can use:

```
$grid->updateColumn($field,array('position'=>$i))
```